# C++ custom allocator: const_pointer 'has not been declared'

Tags: c++, allocator

I have got a problem when writing custom 'allocate' method for custom allocator. According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate) the signature for this method is as following:

```
pointer allocate( size_type n, std::allocator<void>::const_pointer hint = 0 );
```

However, when I define this method for my allocator I have got the message from compiler "'const_pointer’ has not been declared". Below is the pared-down code which shows the problem.

```
template <class T>
class linear_allocator
{
public:
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef const T* const_pointer;

    linear_allocator() {}
    ~linear_allocator() {}

    pointer allocate(unsigned int n, 
                    linear_allocator<void>::const_pointer hint = 0)
    {
      return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
  linear_allocator<double> test_allocator;
}
```

It must be something simple that I am missing, but what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked into stl::allocator implementation (should do it from the start). The problem, as VTT user pointed out, was caused by explicit instantiation of `linear_allocator<void>` inside itself. I though as much myself, but was confused that method definition looks as if it is supposed to work 'as it is'.

Obviously there are many ways to work around this issue -- the simplest would be just use `const void*` as type for `hint`. I was interested to understand why it worked for standard `stl::allocator` and not in my case.

So, after looking into implementation here is the solution:

1. Declare templated class 'linear_allocator'.
2. Define class `linear_allocator` with explicit template name `<void>` -- we need only partial definition of this class -- just type which we are going to use.
3. Define `linear_allocator` for generic template class name.

The working code is below:

```
template <typename T>
class linear_allocator;

template <>
class linear_allocator<void>
{
public:
    typedef void* pointer;
    typedef const void* const_pointer;
};

template <class T>
class linear_allocator
{
public:
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef const T* const_pointer;

    linear_allocator() {}
    ~linear_allocator() {}

    pointer allocate(unsigned int n, 
                     linear_allocator<void>::const_pointer hint = 0)
    {
      return 0;
    }
};
int main()
{
  linear_allocator<double> test_allocator;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by explicit instantiation of `linear_allocator<void>` class template inside of itself. You should probably make it a separate non-template base class instead.

If you are dealing with C++17 then you can simply write this function to match new spec:

```
pointer allocate(std::size_t n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly provide an alias for `void_pointer` and `const_void_pointer` in your allocator. The (optional) requirement in [Allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) is that the parameter matches [`allocator_traits<Alloc>::const_void_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits), which is

> `Alloc::const_void_pointer` if present, otherwise `std::pointer_traits<pointer>::rebind<const void>`

Cleaned up, you get

```
template <class T>
class linear_allocator
{
public:
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef const T* const_pointer;
    typedef void* void_pointer;
    typedef const void* const_void_pointer;
    typedef unsigned int size_type;

    linear_allocator() {}
    ~linear_allocator() {}

    pointer allocate(size_type n, const_void_pointer hint = nullptr)
    {
      return 0;
    }
};
```